# Remove attribute from session before serialize

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee

I saved some references in user sessions that link to objects which aren't serializable.
I would like to remove these attributes from the session before app shut down, before session serialization.

Is there a way to do so?
I already tried with a Listener that listens to app destroy, but sessions are already invalidated at that moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a second class that wraps your first non-serializable into an object reference, and mark it as `transient`:

```
public class Wrapper implements Serializable
{
    public transient YourClass obj;
}
```

`transient` variable won't be serialized upon serialization, and it will be assigned to `null` after deserializarion of `Wrapper` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`HttpSessionActivationListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionActivationListener.html) and implement your cleanup logic in `sessionWillPassivate` method.

```
/**
 * Clean-up listener for removing non-serializable session attributes from session.
 * <p>
 * To activate simply register this class as servlet listener in {@code web.xml}:
 * <pre>
 * &lt;listener>
 *     &lt;listener-class>com.example.SessionCleanupListener&lt;/listener-class>
 * &lt;/listener>
 * </pre>
 */
public class SessionCleanupListener implements HttpSessionListener, HttpSessionActivationListener, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // Register self as session attribute to get `passivation` events
        se.getSession().setAttribute(this.getClass().getName(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionWillPassivate(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();
        Enumeration<String> names = session.getAttributeNames();
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = names.nextElement();
            if (!(session.getAttribute(name) instanceof Serializable)) {
                session.removeAttribute(name);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // no-op
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDidActivate(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // no-op
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to listen to these events but it's not called before serialization of User sessions.

Comment: @PacDroid this listener's sole purpose of existence is to listen on (de)serialization event. Are you sure you are talking about the same listener (there are more than few session related listeners in JEE spec)?

Comment: Yes that's weird, I set up a class which implements ServletContextListener, HttpSessionActivationListener, HttpSessionListener and related methods to implement. I log in each one, but not all methods are invoked on session lifecycle or session pass/activate...

Comment: You need to add this object to session... this listeners works only if set as session attribute. You can add it in [`HttpSessionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/index.html?javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html), which is registered in `web.xml`.

Comment: Ok ok, I'll try it also.

Comment: Added working example of `HttpSessionListener` and `HttpSessionActivationListener` (tested).